# How to convert EU number formatting to a javascript number with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, currency-formatting

I am trying to convert a EU formatted currency amount, say 1.243,51 (equals 1,243.51 in US formatting), to a number in javascript (that would be 1243.51).

I managed to find a large number of examples trying to do very similar things, but I've not been able to adapt it. It seems I need to use regex, which I donøt have much understanding of, but I managed to find some suggestions that almost does the task. I found one regex that replaces the "," with a "." and one which removes ".". I figured I had to do it in two steps, but the problem is that the one which removes "."s also truncates the number behind the dot. This is what I came up with so far:

```
function usToEuCurrencyFormat(input) {
    var output = input.replace(/\./g, '');          //Removes dots
    output = input.replace((/,([^,]*)$/, ".$1"));   //Replaces commas with dots
    return parseFloat(output);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function usToEuCurrencyFormat(input) {
    return input.replace(/[,.]/g, function (x) { return x == "," ? "." : ","; }); }
}
```

This seems to work well enough for me (and just `parseFloat` it if you want a float).

Comment: Great! That's perfect! I like how you chain the methods and I actually understand what the regular expression do now :)

Comment: I think it doesn't work for number with decimal places. Like usToEuCurrencyFormat("10,000.98") => "10.00098" which seems to be very dangerous..

Comment: @Gagan right you are, I've fixed the answer to take that into account.