# Multiply a number which has a comma with javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to multiply a value which contains a comma(lets keep this comma). I cant find anything that seem to work, as everything that I have tried returns as NaN.

```
var value  = 2,55;
// value = 44.000,55 also possible
var amount = 117;
var total  = value * amount;

alert(total);//returns NaN
```

Comment: The first line is invalid syntax. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` You cannot keep the comma there. If you have a string with a comma, convert it to a `Number` first

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: well the number x amount haha

Comment: You'll have to convert it from european format to standard js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651743/how-to-convert-eu-number-formatting-to-a-javascript-number-with-regex

Comment: can you tell us how you get this number, is it an input from user, do you declare it like that, maybe a call from a server ?

Comment: is this monetary syntax? (i.e 1,000 or 2,500,00)

Comment: You should store as pennies and only put in the comma  when printing. There's no easy way other then dividing and splitting and putting back together as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to operate on monetary values, it would be better to get the value as a string and convert it to float then back to string if you want to keep the comma:

```
var value = "2,55";
var amount = 50123123123;
var total = parseFloat(a.replace(',', '')) + b;
total = total.toString().split("").reverse().join("").split('').reduce((a, e, i)=> a + e + (i % 3 === 2 ? ',' : ''), '');

total=total.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var value  = 2,55;
> ```

That is not 2.55; it is 2, a comma and then 55. If I put that into the console of the dev tools of a chromium based browser I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number".

Because it is not valid syntax, in a `var` expression commas are used to define multiple locals.

JavaScript number literals can only use a period as a decimal separator: while parsing functions (converting from strings at runtime) can supper internationalisation the source code does not.

If you are creating code dynamically, the code to create the code has to handle creating syntactically correct code:

```
var value = 2.55; // or 4000.55
```